# Java Generics - Stackoverflow

Tags: java, generics, runtime-error, stack-overflow

I am getting a StackOverflowError from using the following generics:

Points:

```
package me.expdev.gkitpvp;

/*
 * Project created by ExpDev
 */

import me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints;

public abstract class Points {

    private static Points instance = getPointsImpl();

    public static Points getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private static Points getPointsImpl() {
        return new JSONPoints();
    }

    public abstract GLocation getSpawn();

    public abstract void setSpawn(GLocation loc);

    public abstract GLocation getPoint(String id);

    public abstract void addPoint(String id, GLocation loc);

    public abstract void removePoint(String id);

    // LOAD
    public abstract void loadAll();

    // SAVE
    public abstract void forceSaveAll();

}
```

MemoryPoints extending Points:

```
package me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist;

import me.expdev.gkitpvp.GLocation;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.Points;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

/**
 * Project created by ExpDev
 */


public abstract class MemoryPoints extends Points {

    public GLocation spawn = null;
    public Map<String, GLocation> points = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, GLocation>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    public GLocation getSpawn() {
        return spawn;
    }

    public void setSpawn(GLocation spawn) {
        this.spawn = spawn;
    }

    public GLocation getPoint(String id) {
        return points.get(id);
    }

    public void addPoint(String id, GLocation where) {
        points.put(id, where);
    }

    public void removePoint(String id) {
        points.remove(id);
    }

    // LOAD
    @Override
    public abstract void loadAll();

    // SAVE
    @Override
    public abstract void forceSaveAll();


}
```

JSONPoints extending MemoryPoints:

```
package me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json;

import me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryPoints;

/*
 * Project created by ExpDev
 */

public class JSONPoints extends MemoryPoints {

    private JSONSpawn jsonSpawn;
    private JSONRandomPoints jsonRandomPoints;

    public JSONPoints() {
        this.jsonSpawn = new JSONSpawn();
        this.jsonRandomPoints = new JSONRandomPoints();
    }

    // LOADING
    @Override
    public void loadAll() {
        jsonSpawn.load();
        jsonRandomPoints.load();
    }

    // SAVING
    @Override
    public void forceSaveAll() {
        jsonSpawn.forceSave();
        jsonRandomPoints.forceSave();
    }
}
```

JSONSpawn extending JSONPoints:
https://pastebin.com/sgswhBEH

```
package me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.GLocation;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.DiscUtil;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Project created by ExpDev
 */


public class JSONSpawn extends JSONPoints {


    // Info on how to persist
    private Gson gson;
    private File file;

    public JSONSpawn() {
        file = new File(GKitPvPPlugin.p.getDataFolder(), "spawn.json");
        gson = GKitPvPPlugin.gson;
    }

    public Gson getGson() {
        return gson;
    }

    public void setGson(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    public void forceSave() {
        forceSave(true);
    }

    public void forceSave(boolean sync) {
        saveCore(file, this.spawn, sync);
    }

    private boolean saveCore(File target, GLocation data, boolean sync) {
        return DiscUtil.writeCatch(target, this.gson.toJson(data), sync);
    }

    public void load() {
        GLocation spawn = this.loadCore();
        if (spawn == null) {
            return;
        }

        this.spawn = spawn;
        GKitPvPPlugin.p.log("Loaded spawn.");
    }

    private GLocation loadCore() {
        if (!this.file.exists()) {
            return null;
        }

        String content = DiscUtil.readCatch(this.file);
        if (content == null) {
            return null;
        }

        GLocation data = this.gson.fromJson(content, GLocation.class);

        saveCore(this.file, data, true); // Update the flatfile

        return data;
    }
}
```

JSONRandomPoints extending JSONPoints:
https://pastebin.com/C7bEvkxc

```
package me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json;

/*
 * Project created by ExpDev
 */

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.GLocation;
import me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.DiscUtil;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JSONRandomPoints extends JSONPoints {

    // Info on how to persist
    private Gson gson;
    private File file;

    public JSONRandomPoints() {
        file = new File(GKitPvPPlugin.p.getDataFolder(), "points.json");
        gson = GKitPvPPlugin.gson;
    }

    public Gson getGson() {
        return gson;
    }

    public void setGson(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    public void forceSave() {
        forceSave(true);
    }

    public void forceSave(boolean sync) {
        saveCore(file, this.points, sync);
    }

    private boolean saveCore(File target, Map<String, GLocation> data, boolean sync) {
        return DiscUtil.writeCatch(target, this.gson.toJson(data), sync);
    }

    public void load() {
        Map<String, GLocation> points = this.loadCore();
        if (points == null) {
            return;
        }

        this.points.clear();
        this.points.putAll(points);
        GKitPvPPlugin.p.log("Loaded " + points.size() + " points");


    }

    private Map<String, GLocation> loadCore() {
        if (!this.file.exists()) {
            return new HashMap<String, GLocation>();
        }

        String content = DiscUtil.readCatch(this.file);
        if (content == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Map<String, GLocation> data = this.gson.fromJson(
                content,
                new TypeToken<Map<String, GLocation>>() {
                }.getType());

        saveCore(this.file, data, true); // Update the flatfile

        return data;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.Points.<init>(Points.java:9) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryPoints.<init>(MemoryPoints.java:14) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:14) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:15) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:15) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:15) ~[?:?]
        at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~
```

And so it goes on.

-

It's an issue with the generics, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Any solutions?

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do: Both JSONSpawn and JSONRandomPoints are classes used to serialize/deserialize. When for example load() is called in JSONSpawn, it will set the value of spawn in MemoryPoints to the object serialized from the json file. That is for the JSONSpawn class. When load() is called in JSONRandomPoints, it again sets a value in MemoryPoints (class used to handle the setters and getters for the variables), but this time for points. JSONPoints is used so I can be able to call load() in both JSONSpawn and JSONRandomPoints at the same time.

So Points.getInstance().loadAll() will set both variables in MemoryPoints from calling load() in JSONSpawn and JSONRandomPoints. Same goes for saving (which would be the same thing as loading).

For example on program load:

```
Points.getInstance().loadAll().
```

Now variables in MemoryPoints (spawn and points) have been set from calling load() in classes JSONSpawn and JSONRandomPoints. But I would still be able to use:

```
Points.getInstance().getSpawn(); // returns spawn in MemoryPoints
```

Comment: No, a StackOverflowError doesn't have anything to do with generics. You haven't posted the stack trace of the exception, which would allow knowing where the exception happens without having to read every line of the wall of code you posted.

Comment: @JB Nizet see edited post. Added stacktrace.

Comment: That hierarchy is quite a mess I think. My guess is when you instantiate a JSONRandom, it calls the constructor and as it extends from other Points, their constructor is called too. So in some point the constructor from one class is calling the constructor from other and that's making your stack overflows. Try to reorganise the hierarchy or explain to us what you are trying to solve. But certainly the generics don't cause your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I have added some code and explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be abusing inheritance. Anyway, in JSONPoints, you have

```
public JSONPoints() {
    this.jsonSpawn = new JSONSpawn();
    this.jsonRandomPoints = new JSONRandomPoints();
}
```

So, every time you create a JSONPoints instance, it creates a JSONSpawn instance, and a JSONRandomPoints instance.

But both of these classes extend JSONPoints.

So creating a JSONPoints calls the JSONSpawn constructor, which calls its superclass constructor (implicitly), which calls the JSONSpawn constructor, which calls its superclass constructor (implicitly), which calls the JSONSpawn constructor, which ...

Hence the StackOverflowError.

Reading the stack trace makes that clear BTW. You clearly see that the recursive call of both constructors:

```
    at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:14) ~[?:?]
    at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~[?:?]
    at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~[?:?]
    at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONPoints.<init>(JSONPoints.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.json.JSONSpawn.<init>(JSONSpawn.java:22) ~[?:?]
```

I can't really suggest a fix, because I have no idea of what all those classes are for. I can just say that most of these classes probably shouldn't extend from each other.

Comment: Please can you suggest a fix? @JB Nizet

Comment: Change the whole design. Don't use inheritance unless there is a clear is-a association (a Banana is a Fruit). Give clear responsibilities to your classes: either they represent data contained in a JSON document, or they're used to manipulate, save, load data. I can't be clearer than that, because the names and structures of your classes are completely obscure to me. And they have 0 documentation.